# What is the meaning of $\frac{P(A)}{P(A|B)}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In probability theory, the probability of "A and B" is given by

$P(A \wedge B) = P(A) \times P(B|A) = P(A|B) \times P(B)$

If $A$ and $B$ are "independent" this reduces to

$P(A \wedge B) = P(A) \times P(B)$

If I'm not mistaken, $A$ and $B$ are independent if

$\frac{P(A)}{P(A|B)} = \frac{P(B)}{P(B|A)} = 1$

Is this correct? If so, what is the intuitive meaning of this probability $\frac{P(A)}{P(A|B)}$? Does it maybe even have a name?

(I first thought this might be interpreted as the "degree of independence" but it is is a probability of *something*, not just some "degree".)

Comment: Flip a coin twice. The result of the first flip is independent from the second flip. Your ratio arises from P(A|B) = P(A) if A and B are independent. This is because A doesn't depend on B, you can't gain information about A knowing B

Comment: The ratio $P(A)/P(A\mid B)=P(A)P(B)/P(A\cap B)$ can be equal to $1$ (independent case) or smaller than $1$ or larger than $1$. Thus, I doubt any interpretation as a probability exists.

Comment: @HongyuWang You seem to be repeating a part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(A\mid B)}$ isn't a probability. Depending on whether $A$ and $B$ correlate positively or negatively, this ratio can be less than or greater than one, respectively, so neither it, nor its reciprocal can be interpreted as a probability. Its reciprocal, $\frac{\mathsf P(A\mid B)}{\mathsf P(A)}$, measures how much more or less probable $A$ becomes if we learn $B$. The fact that this is equal to $\frac{\mathsf P(B\mid A)}{\mathsf P(B)}$ shows that knowledge of $B$ changes the probability of $A$ by the same factor as knowledge of $A$ changes the probaility of $B$.

Comment: Thanks, I was wrong in assuming it was a probability. But the question about its meaning should still make sense. I'm not sure whether or how the interesting facts about it's reciprocal answers this question though.

Comment: Well, this means that $\frac{\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(A\mid B)}$ *also* measures how much more or less probable $A$ becomes if we learn $B$, but in the opposite direction. A number above 1 means it becomes less probable, and a number below 1 means it becomes more probable.

Comment: @TannerSwett Ah, thanks!